# How to put images in a window showing background image in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

As I can put images in a window that shows a background image in the window, **an important aspect is that the window resizes with the image, which makes it even more difficult for me to insert images over the background image of the window and that all these images are resized with the window**,   `place` seems to work for me, but if I wanted to use `place_forget` it would not work, instead if I use the `grid` to place a widget in the window, a white box appears around this widget in the part bottom of the window.

**Here is an example of what is expected to achieve**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZMCi.jpg

Until now I was able to change the size of the background image but with the other images it is impossible, I ask you please if you can guide me a bit since I am new to programming. **Many thanks.**

Snippet:

```
import os   # os.path.join(), os.listdir()
import sys  # sys.argv
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ResizeCls(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, index, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, kwargs)
        self.image = Image.open (index)
        self.image_copy = self.image .copy()

        self.background = ImageTk.PhotoImage (self.image)

        self.img = Label (self, image= self.background)
        self.img .pack (fill= 'both', expand= True)
        self.img .bind ('<Configure>', self.resize)

    def resize(self, event):
        self.image2 = self.image_copy .resize ((self.master .winfo_width(), self.master .winfo_height()))
        
        self.background2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (self.image2)
        self.img .config (image= self.background2)

class TopCls(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, folder, path_lst=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.folder = folder
        self.path_lst = [os.path.join(self.folder, name) for name in os.listdir(self.folder) if name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.gif'))]

        # Image 1:
        self.frame_image_delay_complete = ResizeCls(self, self.path_lst[0], bd=0)
        self.frame_image_delay_complete       .grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Image 2:
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial = ResizeCls(self, self.path_lst[1], bd=0)
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial       .grid(column=0, row=0)                             # [ NOT POSITIONED ]

        # Text: "Guia"
        self.lbl_text_guia                  = Label(self, text='Insert / hide image', font=('Calibri',7,'bold'), bg='black' , fg='white', bd=0)  
        self.lbl_text_guia                   .place(x=2, y=48)    
        self.lbl_text_guia                    .bind('<Button-1>', self.open_image_miniature)

        # Widgets Not Positioned:  
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_remove()

        # Event: To Posición the label[text= "Guia"]
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.new_position_text_guia)


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def new_position_text_guia(self, event):
        toplevel_width  = self.master.winfo_width() / 35
        toplevel_height = self.master.winfo_height() / 13
        x = int(toplevel_width)
        y = int(toplevel_height)    
     
        self.lbl_text_guia .place(x=x, y=y)

    def open_image_miniature(self, event):
        if self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_info() == {}:
            self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid()
        else:
            self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_remove()







if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    print('if:', folder, len(folder))
else:
    folder = os.getcwd()  # c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\proyecto

root = Tk()
root .geometry('300x300+300+300')
frm = TopCls(root, folder)
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] (also remember that we don't have the images so if possible make the code maybe get them from the internet or substitute them with something else, either how, at least show how you are trying to place those images in a [mre])

Comment: ok, but you still need to provide a [mre], your given code is too long and can't be used to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Matiiss 
If it is long you are right, but how strange that you cannot reproduce it. Here it opens normal.

Comment: well, I managed to get it working, anyways, it seems that you shouldn't size the larger images absolutely but rather proportionally

Comment: @Matiiss proportional? you mean this part ```self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)``` and

```self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)```?

Comment: Your code is working. Using Python 3.12.1. I can see the image resizing.